# Seeking tools or open source library to deal with LIDAR data(mobile laser scan data)

Tags: software-recommendations, lidar, open-source-gis

I would like to do some research job relating to automatic objects extraction along the road, like road markings, pole-like objects.

I have to pre-process the original data before applying my own algorithm, including segmentation of huge datasets, filtering of road poins, and feature image generation.

What tools or open source lib can I use?

Answer (score 2):

LAS tools are great for processing of LiDAR data, they exist as a standalone program or as an ArcGIS toolbox:

http://rapidlasso.com/lastools/